# How to configure FreemarkerTag in JSP

Tags: freemarker, taglib

I try to use the FreemarkerTag in a JSP. I was wondering a bit because the distribution lacks a TLD file, but I created one on my own:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taglib>
    <tlibversion>1.0</tlibversion>
    <jspversion>1.1</jspversion>
    <shortname>fmtag</shortname>
    <info>Taglib for freemarker in JSP</info>
    <uri>http://adesso.ch/jsp/fmtag</uri>
  <tag>
    <name>template</name>
    <tagclass>freemarker.ext.jsp.FreemarkerTag</tagclass>
    <bodycontent>tagdependent</bodycontent>
    <info>Allows evaluation of FreeMarker templates inside JSP</info>
    <attribute>
      <name>caching</name>
      <required>false</required>
    </attribute>
  </tag>
</taglib>
```

I can use the FreemarkerTag with this and do basic things (like string concats + loops). I can't use it for example to use the include directive like this:

```
<fm:template>
  <#include "dummy_product_box_page_67623.ftl">
</fm:template>
```

In this case, the template to include won't be found. I don't have a clue how to configure my main template in more detail. Especially, for the include directive, I don't find a way to configure the TemplatePath.
I found lots of examples how to do it programmatically via setDirectoryForTemplateLoading() on the config object, but I don't have programmatic access in my scenario.

Any hints and ideas would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It uses `Configuration.getDefaultConfiguration()`, so that's the configuration instance you have to configure on some very early stage, like preferably before any HTTP request processing threads are started. Note however, that `Configuration.getDefaultConfiguration()` is deprecated because what's if some other component, one that you don't even know about, sets up that singleton for itself too. But that's how it is with that poor abandoned tag right now anyway... (I guess it should get the `Configuration` from the Servlet request scope as an attribute, and failing that, from the application context.).

Comment: Since we don't really have a controller in our scenario and there is almost no Java code we use, this is not our preferred solution. But definitively your hint helped a lot for clarifying how it works. Thanks.